# GnuPG symmetric encryption yields different output

Tags: encryption, cryptography, gnupg

I have a use case where I want to commit symmetrically encrypted source code using GnuPG (think of [Coursera](http://coursera.org) assignments for backup and collaboration). I encrypt/decrypt all sources in a batch with a script and was wondering, why the output is not stable.

So basically, why does

```
echo "plain text" | gpg --armor --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256
```

with password `secret` yield different cipher texts with each call? (Surely enough, this doesn't affect the decryption – different cipher texts may decrypt back to the same plain text.)
I am not experienced with crypto algorithms, but skimming the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) it seems the algorithm is deterministic.

So in short, my questions are:

1. Is this behaviour a property of AES or am I using GnuPG incorrectly?
2. If the former is the case, are there other symmetric crypto algorithms which are better suited for this use case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually, symmetric encryption starts with a random initialization vector (IV). [OpenPGP uses a slightly different cypher feedback mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.7) with an all-zero IV, but the first two blocks are random.

Because of this, also the symmetric encryption is not deterministic; you cannot compare the plain text by comparing the encrypted message, the encrypted result is not deterministic any more.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the encryption *initialization vector* (IV), the symmetric key derivation uses a random salt to protect against offline dictionary or rainbow table attacks.  Specifically, the [Iterated and Salted S2K](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.3) (*String-to-Key*) packet contains an 8-byte salt.

Answer (score 3):

Approaching your second question, rather than using a different crypto algorithm, you can replace `gpg` in symmetric mode with `openssl`:

```
echo "plain text" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:secret
```

Beware:

- For sample purposes, I am providing the passphrase in the command line. See [PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS](http://man.cx/openssl#heading5) in openssl(1) for better ways of providing it.
- As we are explicitely disabling the salt, you should a stronger passphrase that is not reused, I would use a long randomly generated passphrase that changes for each assignment,